# how to store temporary attributes on an Active Record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to store some debug messages on an object as it can go through processing but I don't want to be storing this to the database. Is something like this a reasonable way, an instance variable wrapped in a method with a nil guard? Or is there a better way / pattern?

```
class Bid < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def debug_reasons
     @debug_reasons ||= []
  end
  ...
```

and then

```
bid.debug_reasons << "here is a reason"
```

Comment: Sure, that seems fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is `attribute`

```
class Bid < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :debug_reasons, :default => []
end
```

More info on `attribute` http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute

Comment: Based on the docs, it seems that `attribute` is used in relation to a database column. Am I mis-reading that?

Comment: @jvillian it works in the model also `attribute :my_int_array, :integer, array: true` check that part

Comment: Oh wow. I'm sorry. It says right there in black-and-white: "Attributes do not need to be backed by a database column." Apologies.

Comment: nice solution - wasn't familiar with this feature. will be using in future. This is why I will ask a lot of ?'s on SO.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes I would use logging with the appropriate log level. This way the object behavior does not get messed up with the debugging.

In addition, the debug log level can (should) be disabled in production environments, but adding logic inside your models will not make it so easy.

Comment: thx - the question probably wasn't worded as well. This is 'debugging' for why values are a certain way (ie nonexistent) for sales managers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Bustikiller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084180/916996) that, for debugging purposes, logging the messages is a better option rather than changing your production code.

But, If you really need it, I would use the ruby `attr_accessor` method rather than the [ActiveRecord::Base.attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute) method because the former doesn't expose an internal attribute as a model attribute.

The model attributes should be properties of the entity your model implements. A debug/internal method (such as #object_id and #to_s) should not be considered as an attribute and, therefore, they should not appear on attribute list (i.e. when you call `#attributes` on a model instance). By using the `.attribute` from ActiveRecord, you define `debug_messages` as an attribute of `Bid` which, I think, may not be an property of your Bid domain.

So, using the `attr_accessor` you don't pollute the ActiveModel API with an internal/logic attribute.